# data.frame row logical subsetting based on string prefix

Tags: r, dplyr

using `base::startsWith` logical test to filter a data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "Make") #sample df 
df_sub <- filter(df, startsWith(Make, c("Mas","Maz","Mer")))
```

produces unexpected results, i.e. only one Mazda and & 2 Merc and there are more matches in the `df`. is there a similar approach as I feel `RegEx` would be an overdo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `str_detect` (from `select_helpers` to match regex substring)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     filter(str_detect(Make, (str_c(c("^Mas", "^Maz", "^Mer"), collapse="|"))))
#             Make  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1      Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2  Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3      Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#4       Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#5       Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#6      Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#7     Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#8     Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#9    Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#10 Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: i did look at `starts_with` from `select_helpers` but it appears it was not the intended use, i.e., only to select columns by name? 


  [1]: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyselect/versions/0.2.5/topics/select_helpers

Comment: @Vrun. Usage would be `vars_select(df$Make, starts_with("Mas"))` but it is used in a different context and here it iss not returning logical vector which the `filter` needs

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
filter(df, substr(Make, 1, 3) %in% c("Mas","Maz","Mer"))

            Make  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1      Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3      Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
4       Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
5       Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6      Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
7     Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
8     Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
9    Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
10 Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Also a possibility:

```
prefix <- c("Mas","Maz","Mer")
df[apply(sapply(prefix, function(x) startsWith(df$Make, x)), 1, any), ]
```

Also the second possibility could be used in `dplyr::filter()`, although it is not very tidy:

```
filter(df, apply(sapply(prefix, function(x) startsWith(Make, x)), 1, any))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df[grepl("^Mas|^Maz|^Mer", df$Make),]
#OR
df[grepl(paste(paste0("^", c("Mas","Maz","Mer")), collapse = "|"), df$Make),]
#            Make  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1      Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2  Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#8      Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#9       Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#10      Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#11     Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#12    Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#13    Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#14   Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#31 Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: can be `df[grepl("^(Mas|Maz|Mer)", df$Make),]` as prefix is always at the beginning